# node.js в каком порядке будут исполнены функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность, event-loop

есть вопрос по event loop.

У меня есть структура данных.
У меня есть веб сокеты, я слушаю сообщения от пользователей и выполняю некоторые функции, в том числе которые работают с этой структурой данных.
Также у меня есть таймер, который каждую секунду вызывает функцию, которая тоже может работать с этой структурой данных.

Получается что-то такое:

```
const store = {...};

ws.on('message', function socketFunction(data) {
  socketFunction1();
  socketFunction2();
  socketFunction3();
});

function timerFunction(){
  timerFunction1();
  timerFunction2();
  timerFunction3();
};

setInterval(1000, timerFunction);
```

Собственно вопрос: могу ли я быть уверен, что если уж то, что внутри функции socketFunction начало исполняться, то оно исполнится до конца и только тогда исполнится то, что внутри функции timerFuntion?

Ну и, соответственно, наоборот.

Не может ли выполниться socketFunction1(), socketFunction2(), а потом отработает таймер и начнет выполняться  timerFunction1(), timerFunction2(), timerFunction3()?

Comment: Если все функции синхронны, то не может

Comment: а если, допустим, внутри socketFunction2(); есть обращение к базе данных? Получается тогда между этими функциями могут вклиниться другие функции?

Comment: @IIITSTIIIMEEE, нужны конкретные примеры функций и твое определение, что значит "вклиниться"

Comment: @grundy да вот по сути конкретный пример. Всё то же самое, что я написал в своём посте, только в socketFunction2(); есть обращение к базе данных await db.query(). Может ли быть такое, что функция socketFunction дойдет до вызова базы данных, потом отработает таймер и исполнится функция timerFunction(), а потом база данных выполнит запрос, вернет результат и дальше исполнится socketFunction3();

Comment: @IIITSTIIIMEEE, конкретный пример это как раз, когда есть примеры содержимого функций. Для кода предоставленного в вопросе, именно вызовы будут по порядку, при этом, если есть асинхронные операции, то в текущем примере даже соседние функции могут выполняться, пока ожидается асинхронный ответ